# Using functions defined inside vue distributed file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nodes, node-modules

I have been working with vuejs and everything seem quite alright but recently i decided to check the vue file which is in distributed file that is `vue.js` inside the dist folder of vue npm package.

My question is how can i be able to use any of the functions directly on my project example of the functions i saw there is

```
// vue.js inside dist folder of the npm vue package
/**
   * Merge an Array of Objects into a single Object.
   */
  function toObject (arr) {
    var res = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i]) {
        extend(res, arr[i]);
      }
    }
    return res
  }
```

If it is possible I want to be directly using those functions on my project as a helper functions.

Comment: did u try `window.toObject(param)`?

Comment: @Christiano  I haven't. I will try that and see if it's available in the window scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unless the function is `exported`, you cannot use that function via import.

Before you try to import you need to understand bundle resolution rules and check what kind of file it is:

```
// ES Module
export function toObject(arr) { /* */ }

// Common.js Module
module.exports.toObject = function toObject(arr) { /* */ }

// Global/UMD
window.toObject = function toObject(arr) { /* */ }
```

Typically, the module bundler will figure out the type of module and allow you to use **import** statement in you code like:

```
import { toObject } from 'vue';
```

Module bundler like Webpack uses `main` or `module` field in the `package.json` file of the package to determine the actual file to use. So if your dist folder contains multiple files, the bundler knows exactly which file to pick up.

Also, if you want to import from a file that is not specified in `main` or `module` field, then use can use package relative paths. For example, your `dist` folder has two files: - `vue.js` and `helper.js` and the `main` field is set to `dist/vue.js`, then saying just `import * as x from 'vue'` will always import from `dist/vue.js` file.

However, if you need to import from `helper.js` file, then use something like:

```
import * as x from 'vue/dist/helper.js';
import { something } from 'vue/dist/helper.js';
```

**Again, import is possible only if given function or value is exported by that file** (using any of module/commonjs/global exports). In your case, the function is not exported outside as we can see from the code and hence, you cannot import it and use it in your code.

As a workaround, you can simply copy the code and use it in your application.

Comment: Thanks so much for for the explanation.